# Trigger travis ci builds if another git repository updates

Tags: github, travis-ci

Let's say that I have a git repository `A` and another git repository `B`. I have my `.travis.yml` file in `A` repository. Now I want to trigger travis build whenever there is a commit in `B` repository. Can someone show me the complete precedure on how this is done?

Comment: Did you see https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/triggering-builds ? If yes, you probably should add where you're stuck.