# How to trigger E2E tests when repositories are changed or pull requests added?

Tags: github, travis-ci, e2e-testing

The only similar question I found is the following: [Trigger travis ci builds if another git repository updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37568519/trigger-travis-ci-builds-if-another-git-repository-updates)

Keep in mind that our E2E tests are full stack: we have a live server running, and our tests are run against the UI which hits the server. Nothing is stubbed or mocked.

Now, I can trigger in that way a travis rebuild, however problem arises when I have interdependency between branch and a different repository branch.

So let's say I have 3 repositories: `backend`, `frontend` and `e2etests`. If I create the new branch `frontend/foo` which requires also the `backend/foo`, there is no way e2e tests will ever pass because they will run one time with `frontend/foo` and `backend/master` and another time with `frontend/master` and `backend/foo`.

Did anyone face this problem previously? How did you deal with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of digging it was clear that there is no solution and everyone has their own built-in.

What worked for us is a git pre-push hook, environment variables pointing to our repositories and when you push it asks if you want to use a different branch for the UI project (if you are on the UI, asks if you want to use a different branch for the server project) and by default it uses the current branch for the project you are on. So it's quite fast on push, usually you'll just press ENTER an additional time, the two branches are basically the required dependencies and a travis build will be triggered with an API endpoint.

Works fine so far.